# My wifi has stopped working, unclaimed network?

Tags: wifi, networking

Like the title says, my wifi card seems to have stopped working. My ethernet is working fine though. The results from my lshw -C network are as followed

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:c1b00000-c1b03fff
```

If anyone could help me out it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED. I followed the steps in this guide [wiki.debian](https://wiki.debian.org/brcm80211#Installation) and it was able to fix my problem. Just needed to reinstall the brcmsmac driver